# What is the difference between Nav and NavController's push method

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building an Ionic app and major part of building an app of course is navigation from one page to another.

I am new to Ionic and I am not sure what is used mostly for what, right now I am using whatever seems to work but in the long run it may be useful to know beforehand what's better.

Nav and NavController's `push` method seems to be doing very much the same thing, pushes a page / component onto the stack.

I've used both of them interchangeably on different parts of the app so I am now concerned whether it is a problem.

```
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  public openMessageListPage() {
    this.nav.push(MessageListPage);
  }
}
```

And then also this

```
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MessageListPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {}

  notificationItemDetail(evt, item) {
    this.navCtrl.push( MessageItemPage );
  }

}
```

The functions are being called from elements in the template, both seem to do the job as expected, though it bugs me why there are two of such modules that does the same job, there has to be some differences in their functions, going through the docs didn't provide me with much info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has 3 places mainly. You can read more about this on [**official doc here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

**Note:** I got all the information from the doc.But if you have any specific clarification about below information feel free to ask in the comments section.

**1. Navigating from the Root component**

Here you can't inject `NavController` because any components that are navigation controllers are children of the `root` component. So they aren't available to be injected.

By adding a reference variable to the `ion-nav`, you can use `@ViewChild` to get an instance of the `Nav` component which is a navigation controller (it extends `NavController`):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
   template: '<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
})
export class MyApp {
   @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController
   public rootPage: any = TabsPage;

   // Wait for the components in MyApp's template to be initialized
   // In this case, we are waiting for the Nav with reference variable of "#myNav"
   ngOnInit() {
      // Let's navigate from TabsPage to Page1
      this.nav.push(Page1);
   }
}
```

**2. Navigating from an Overlay Component**

When you need to navigate from an overlay component (popover, modal, alert, etc) you need to to get a reference of the root NavController using the `getRootNav()` method.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    template: `
    <ion-content>
      <h1>My PopoverPage</h1>
      <button ion-button (click)="pushPage()">Call pushPage</button>
     </ion-content>
    `
  })
  class PopoverPage {
    constructor(
      public viewCtrl: ViewController
      public appCtrl: App
    ) {}

    pushPage() {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
      this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(SecondPage);
    }
  }
```

**3. View creation (i.e. Pushing a View)**

If you need to push a new view onto the navigation stack, use the `push` method.

```
export class StartPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  pushPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage, {
      id: "123",
      name: "Carl"
    });
  }
}
```